# code example "switch" (b.eckel) doesn't buil/run on Xcode but build/run on QT

Tags: c++, switch-statement, case

This code is ok on QT SDK (installed on Windows) but reports expected expression error on Xcode 4 (Mac).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    bool quit = false; // Flag for quitting
    while(quit == false) {
        cout << "Select a, b, c or q to quit: ";
        char response;
        cin >> response;
        switch(response) {
        case 'a' :
            cout << "you chose 'a'" << endl;
            break;
        case 'b' :
            cout << "you chose 'b'" << endl;
            break;
        case 'c' :
            cout << "you chose 'c'" << endl;
            break;
        case 'q' :
            cout << "quitting menu" << endl;
            quit = true;
            break;
        default :
            cout << "Please use a,b,c or q!" << endl;
        }
    }
} ///:~
```

The error is displayed on default instruction: "expected expression".

Comment: Please tell us which line the error occurs on, and quote the exact error message.

Comment: Was this IDE "error" highlight, or error reported by compiler when compiling?

Comment: It might have something related to not having a `return` statement from `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Issue but I didn't understand its root.
Assuming that the copied code from Eckel's book on QT sdk gave no error, I tried to delete some blank space preceding the first closed curly brace and so I got a build/run successful on Xcode platform too. Isn't it strange? Boh the mistery of SW.

Comment: It might be that, in copying the code, some spaces got replaced with different, space-like characters (for example U+00A0, non-breaking space) that the compiler could not understand. When you deleted some of that blank space, it turned out to include the offending character(s).